# Bootstrap style not applied to dynamic element

Tags: bootstrap-4

Another noob question, so I apologize...

I dynamically add a `<tr>` with few `<button>` in one of the cells. Those buttons do not have a proper padding after addition. I tried to force re-rendering, but it doesn't help.

I created a jsfiddle with the issue https://jsfiddle.net/phi1ipp/8ge6phk7/4/

[image: Second row added with a jQuery]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you statically add them, you are putting a space between the buttons
html displays the single space, and ignores multiple. to duplicate the dynamic effect, you would have to remove any space between the elements

when you dynamically add them, you do not have a space .. so no space is included and the butt up to each other

```
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-sm">ok</button><button class="btn btn-sm">ko</button>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you, such a dumb queastion. I'm ashamed

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Jquery append method removes the default margin in the button. But you can override the style by adding a class to format your button's margin.

In your css, you can add another class for formatting the margin of your button:

```
.btn-style{margin-right: 4px;}
```

In your javascript, you do this:

```
$('tbody').append('<tr><td>2</td><td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-style">oo</button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-style">uu</button></td></tr>')
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a single **white space character** between buttons in latter one.

```js
$('tbody').append('<tr><td>2</td><td><button class="btn btn-sm">oo</button> <button class="btn btn-sm">uu</button></td></tr>')
```

Comment: Thank you, absolutely missed it!